# Complex Fraction $\left(\frac{4a}{2a^3+2}\right)/\left(\frac{8a}{4a+4}\right)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$$\frac{\frac{4a}{2a^3+2}}{\frac{8a}{4a+4}}$$

I have a question regarding special polynomials. If I see a binomial, such as, $a^3+1$ and the $1$ does not have a $3$ as an exponent. Why should I assume there is a one there? I would like someone to convince me. It seems deceiving to arbitrarily assign exponent of $3$ to a term that obviously or at least visually does not have one.

I am taking a calculus I course, and I am practicing my algebra. Thus, it is very important I understand these axioms. [image]

Comment: you understand that $1^3 = 1.$ if the exponent is not there you can insert it as long as the equivalence is valid. e.g. $-1 = (-1)^3$ and you can use that to factor $x^3 - 1 = x^3 + (-1)^3 = (x-1)(x^2 + x + 1).$

Comment: $1^2=1^{34}=1^{-3}=1^{3}=1$. You are not assuming there is a 3 in the exponent, it is there. Of course, if you had $x^5 + 1$, you should write it $x^5+1^5$ to help you find the correct factorization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider cancellation as a division:

$$\frac{F}{FG}=\frac{F}{F}\times\frac{1}{G}$$

Then you replace $\frac{F}{F}$ with $1$ with condition that $F\neq 0$

This is the mechanism of cancellation in fractions.

In your case:

$$\frac{a+1}{(a+1)(a^2-a+1)}=\frac{a+1}{a+1}\times\frac1{(a^2-a+1)}=\frac1{(a^2-a+1)}$$

Comment: Is the method I utilized the best to arrive at an answer for a complex fraction question?

Comment: So although 2/2 is 1 I should put the 1's there?

Comment: Was my mistake...

Comment: btw, better to replace $(2)2a^3+2$ with $(2)(2a^3+2)$ since the space makes no difference in order of operations while parenthesis does. (Although the examiner understand what you mean)

Answer (score 0):

For most symbols, you are completely correct--you can't just arbitrarily assign or change an exponent.

However, the numbers $0$ and $1$ have the very special property that $0^n=0$ and $1^n=1$ for any positive number $n$. So in these two special cases, we can supply or change to any positive exponent we want. But it would be wrong to write $5^3$, say, in place of $5$. This only works with $0$ and $1$.

Answer (score 0):

Proceeding from special to general is somewhat more involved than from special to the general.

I like to ask, if instead you were given :

$$ \dfrac{\dfrac{4a}{2 a^3 + 2 b^3}}{\dfrac{8a}{4 a + 4 b}} $$

I put in 1 = b in your (complex) fraction to preserve degree in each of the four given terms.

Perhaps you can now answer your own question while attempting to simplify.